# how to access embedded components' PropTypes?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Having composition of elements like

```
function ExtendedPasswordInput({ forceValidation, ...props }) {
    return <>
            <input type="password" {...props} />
            <Tooltip forceValidation={forceValidation} />
        </>;
}

ExtendPasswordInput.propTypes = {
    validation: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

So here I'm passing every extra props to `<input />` inside. I want to extend `propTypes` to reflect that:

```
ExtendPasswordInput.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    onKeyPress: PropTypes.func,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func,
    onBlur: PropTypes.func,
    // ... a lot of other <input>-specific props

    validation: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

I'd expect to use something like

```
ExtendPasswordInput.propTypes = {
    ...input.propTypes,
    validation: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

but surely this does not work since `input is not defined`. Is it possible to import native components explicitly to get their `propTypes`?

So far checked named imports from packages `react` and `react-dom` with no luck.

Even tried `(<input />).constructor.propTypes` but it returns `undefined`.

I know in TypeScript it's possible to

```
interface ExtendedPasswordInputProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement> { }
```

but how to achieve that with PropTypes only?

Comment: just export/ import the props type object

Comment: @plat123456789 how could I import `<input />`'s prop type object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any way to achieve that.

Moreover I believe it'd be rather shoot-in-a-foot.

Components `propTypes` is a kind of interface, public contract. And extending this with `...someOthersPropType` anyway has its drawback: you don't have control over both - "base" component you want to extend by wrapping and also you cannot control code uses your "wrapper" component.

Making a component that assures "I support everything that ... supports" makes it's impossible(or really risky) to replace some generic component with custom one having more limited props. Just because you cannot know what props client code already relies on when calling that *wrapper* component.

Actually any refactoring that touches that nested component would be painful.

On the other side listing props explicitly allows you narrow your *wrapper* component commitment. So every extra prop client code uses it's on their risk.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but this should work. You're looking for an element here (input) and the Tooltip instance:

```
ExtendedPasswordInput.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    PropTypes.instanceOf(Tooltip)
  )
};
```

Comment: does it allow me to apply say `disabled` prop(that is legit for `<input />`) for my component with validation passed?

Comment: As long as it is present it will fulfill the propTypes as it's expecting an array of two elements, the <input /> and the <Tooltip />

Comment: I see what you mean. But don't want passing random components in my `ExtendedPasswordInput`. It surely solves thing with validation(since I'll not need to pass `onClick` to my `<ExtendedPasswordInput onClick=...` directly) but code becomes much more verbose and I don't need such a flexibility here.